Поиск похожих изображений на десктопе
Появилась задача найти картинки похожие на исходник.
Причем интересны 2 варианта:

поиск в локальной папке windows
поиск по полю ImageFile в Django

Яндекс и Гугл умеют искать по картинке, но не локально, а в интернете. Как это сделать локально? Интересны возможные решения с обучением нейросетей с соответствующими библиотеками.

Приплетать нейросети куда попало это ещё ладно, а django-то тут при чём?

Возможно, существуют готовые решения. Так например, GPT4 мне предложил на основе библиотеки DIM. К тому же изначально проект на Django. А картинки в папке Media. Пути представляют собой дату, по которой не сложно найти исходные данные в таблице. Поэтому достаточно найти, где лежит картинка, то есть путь. По поводу нейросетей - а как вы себе представляете найти похожее изображение без нейросети? :)))) Поясню - например, по фото стола, надо найти другую картинку этого же стола в базе данных (или в папке)

Я бы смотрел в сторону OpenCV, а не нейросетей...
